# Volume path or Mount in Windows container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**Description**
I got error "Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path" in Windows Container

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**
  1. DockerFile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build AS base
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "Test.dll" ]
```

2. Run command `docker build -t docker-vol .`
3. Run Command `docker run -it -p 8001:80 -v D:\Projects\Docker\publish:c:/app --name docker-vol-test docker-vol` (This works)
4. Run Command `docker run -it -p 8001:80 --mount "source=D:\Projects\Docker\publish,target=c:/app" --name docker-vol-test docker-vol` This fails with `Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid volume name`

I am wondering how to work with --mount and whether it is possible to use relative path instead of absolute path with -v?

Answer (score 4):

You are using a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), but because you have not specified a `type`, then it has defaulted to `volume`. In this case, `source` must be the name of the volume, or omitted for an anonymous volume.

Because you have give a path instead, you are getting this error. If you add a `type` key to your command, it should work:

```
docker run -it -p 8001:80 --mount 'type=bind, source="D:\Projects\Docker\publish", target="c:/app"' --name docker-vol-test docker-vol
```

In answer to your second point, bind mounts require an absolute path. The usual way to use a relative path in Linux-land is to prepend the path with `$PWD`. In Windows, the equivalent of `SPWD` would be `%cd%`, so if you were running from `D:\Projects\Docker`, then the above would probably be:

```
docker run -it -p 8001:80 --mount 'type=bind, source="%cwd%\publish", target="c:/app"' --name docker-vol-test docker-vol
```

Note that I have no experience of Docker under Windows, but I believe the above should work.

Comment: Great, before accepting this answer, I want to confirm whether it is able to use relative path and if I want to use type with `volume`, how could I try?

Answer (score 0):

The above is correct but if you want to use `-v` instead  the syntax is: `docker run -v C:\SomePath:C:\app\somePath image`
Note the path must exist or the command fails.